# Generate an infinite custom object stream in Java

Tags: java

Assuming I have a simple data class like this, I'd like to create a randomly generated stream of objects of *Pack* class with random values in its two properties.

```
class Pack {
  int millisecondTime; //System.currentmillis
  double weight;
}
```

I do not want the stream to wait until it is being read to generate more items, so I would run this in a background thread.

I can create a stream of integers using `IntStream.iterate` but don't know how to do this for a custom object. Is there something similar in the `Stream` interface I can use?

Comment: *"I do not want the stream to wait until it is being read to generate more items, so I would run this in a background thread"* — Well, I would initially drop this requirement. I think for the current use case, it makes things more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: "I do not want the stream to wait until it is being read to generate more items" what happens if nothing reads the items? Do you just keep making more until you OOM? How expensive are these things to create that you can't just make them on demand?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns an infinite sequential unordered stream where each element is
>  * generated by the provided {@code Supplier}.  This is suitable for
>  * generating constant streams, streams of random elements, etc.
>  *
>  * @param <T> the type of stream elements
>  * @param s the {@code Supplier} of generated elements
>  * @return a new infinite sequential unordered {@code Stream}
>  */
> ```

```
public static<T> Stream<T> generate(Supplier<T> s) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(s);
    return StreamSupport.stream(
            new StreamSpliterators.InfiniteSupplyingSpliterator.OfRef<>(Long.MAX_VALUE, s), false);
}
```

According to the documentation, you just need to pass a supplier.

Example:

```
Stream.generate(() -> yourMethodWhichReturnsObject());
```

Answer (score 1):

`Stream` can [`generate` an infinite stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate(java.util.function.Supplier)) using a `Supplier`:

```
Random r = new Random();
Stream<Pack> stream = Stream.generate(() -> new Pack(r.nextInt(), r.nextDouble()));
stream.limit(10).forEach(p -> process(p));
```

Using `Random` as just an example. Your implementation can differ.